# JSPM bundling with external system js file

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, jspm

I am loading my angular2 file as a System js module from CDN.

I have several files which imports various system js modules of angular2.

Now I want to bundle my local javascript files using JSPM. When I write the command

```
  "jspm bundle app/main build.js"
```

JSPM fails. As JSPM is trying to find angular2 folder in my project. I know the reason that it checks the map defined in config.js. But I want to know how to overcome this. As I don't want to install angular2 file in my local project, and I definitely don't want to serve angular2 file from my server to client's browser, I want to use CDN.

Please help.

Comment: Why do you not want it bundled in?  JSPM is a module bundler in that it encapsulates dependencies and fetches them when a module imports them.  It cannot do this dynamic loading from a CDN, unless you have some sort of hackish fetching mechanism built into your code.  To my knowledge, JSPM (and any other module bundler) expects you to have your dependencies explicitly declared and installed locally so that they can all be bundled together as needed.

Comment: @ryanlutgen - I want the same exact result which you are saying but I want to load other system js modules from CDN. And of course I don't want them in my build.js. Ex. - I am loading angular2 systemJs module from cdn and I have local modules like - app1.js, app2.js.....so on. I want to make a bundle called app.js which contains all my local modules. And then use this bundle alongwith angular2 module which I am loading from CDN. The problem is - I cannot bundle my local modules, as the need angular2 module, and angular2 module is not conffigured in jspm, I am loading that module from CDN.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At last I found the answer to do this:

System Js config option also takes a meta info. In this meta info we can write to ignore modules of SystemJs from being bundled. So lets say I am loading all the angular2 modules from cdn, importing them in local modules and then building it with systemJs or JSPM, then I must write the following in config.js(or inside System.config's options object):

```
meta: {
        'angular2/*': {
            build: false
        },
        'rxjs/add/operator/map' : {
            build : false
        }
    }
```

This should be put in config.js by angular2 developers to explicitly tell systemJs to avoid looking for angular2 modules and rxjs modules while bundling the local modules. This will provide you the opportunity to load angular2 and rxjs from cdn and consequently not include them in the map option of config.js.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to build and use CDN at the same time (because you configured some packages to load from CDN *with* SystemJS), you can build everything *but* the CDN packages. For example:

```
jspm bundle app/main.js - angular2 - whatever + somethingelse main-bundle.js --inject
```

Otherwise, simplier, you can put the CDN links directly inside you index.html files and use SystemJS for local packages only.

Comment: Hi, It doesn't work. If you are importing say "jQuery" in your local development module but loading jQuery's module from CDN in index.html file, you will get systemJS error while bundling. This is because SystemJs tries to find "jQuery" in the map of config.js